# Reading more than two Arduino sensors

Tags: python, arduino

For a university project, I need to write a python script that uses the data of some Arduino ultrasonic sensors. I managed to glue together a way to read one using tutorials found on google, but I don't really know if it's applicable to more of them.

Here's the Arduino code:

```
int trigPin = 11;    // Trigger
int echoPin = 12;    // Echo
long duration, cm, inches;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  cm = (duration/2) / 29.1;     // Divide by 29.1 or multiply by 0.0343

  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.println();

  delay(250);
}
```

Just a basic ultrasonic sensor code, easy to add more sensors if needed.

And here is the python code, where the problem lies.

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9800)
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    line = ser.readline()   # read a byte
    if line:
        string = line.decode()  # convert the byte string to a unicode string
        num = int(string) # convert the unicode string to an int
        print(num)

ser.close()
```

I'm going tp admit that I really get 100% how the python script is reading the serial output from the Arduino, but I tested it and it worked.

My question is, can this method be used with more than one sensor, and if it can, how can I implement it?

Comment: To read two sensors at the same time will require them to be on two differenct COM changes, so you'll need to do that initially. After that is should be more or less reading a line from one of them and then other. Do you now know "get" how to proceed?

Comment: @martineau - I've read the question as wanting to connect multiple sensors on a single arduino rather than connecting to multiple arduinos. Perhaps the poster can clarify.

Comment: @cguk70: Perhaps. Hard to tell for sure because the OP said "uses the data of some Arduino ultrasonic sensors" which sounded like more than one Arduino to me.

Comment: clarification: yes its multiple sensors on a single arduino. i do get that the way the script is reading the entries is through a individual COM port, wich is why i had a hunch that this method might need tweaking to work with multiple sensors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can - I've run 5 ultrasonic sensors on an Arduino transmitting the results over serial to a python program.

You can either read all the distances at the same time and send them in a single string with a separator. Eg. "12:23:45”. In python use `string.split(':')` to separate into individual values.

Or send them one at a time with an identifier (useful if sensors are read at different rates). Eg "dist1:12" and "dist2:23" and use the same `split()` function to separate the identifier and the value.

Comment: i did considered obtaining different sensor information through string separation, but didn't knew about string.split().